# Using multiple internet connections on ubuntu

Tags: internet, broadband

My network topology is as follows:

PC (1 nic) ======> Switch =======> 2 routers (192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.11).

The PC has only 1 nic (ethernet port).
Both routers connected to their respective isps.

Need a quick and simple way to make Ubuntu use both the broadband connections.

Please dont point me to Bonding (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding)
That is a different thing, bonding combines 2 nics into 1.

I need to use 2 routers at the same time (like having 2 gateways at the same time)

Comment: It can't be 192.168.11.

Comment: I'm not sure if the stock Ubuntu is compiled with channel bonding, but that with two nics is what you really want (or a device with channel bonding between the switch and the routers)

Comment: another one: http://johnlewis.ie/bonding-teaming-internet-connections/ :)

Comment: @Radu It can be anything, just configure the router's ip address.

Comment: @SilverMoon No, it can't, look here: [IPv4 addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#IPv4_addresses).

Comment: @Radu ok its 192.168.1.11 (typing mistake)

Answer (score 0):

You need a switch, that is capable of doing the bonding. Those switches are business class devices, usually with 24 or 48 ports, even 12 port office class switches can't do that typically.

Another possible solution is a gateway-server with 3 ethernet ports.

Comment: that page talks about bonding 2 nics into 1, not 2 internet connections into 1

Comment: @Rinzwind what will I need ? I have got only 1 nic on my pc, and on the other side of the Lan switch there are 2 routers. So please explain a bit more in detail in a separate answer.

Comment: Sorry I missed a few words. You can not do that with that setup. You need a dedicated server for this to work.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question, changed the answer.